# Entity Framework 4 - Get generated SQL for Updates/Inserts

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

With EF4, is it possible to get the generated SQL for Updates/Inserts rather than executing it... just like you can view the query SQL before it runs.

The reason is, I have a set of helper functions that execute SQL commands.  For instance...

```
Decrement<Category>("ProductCount", categoryID);
SetNull<Product>("CategoryID", productID);
```

Which generates...

```
UPDATE Categories 
SET ProductCount = ProductCount - 1 
WHERE CategoryID = @CategoryID; 

UPDATE Products 
SET CategoryID = NULL 
WHERE CategoryID = @ProductID;
```

I usually run several commands per operation, so with each helper function call, the SQL is generated and stored.  When I call SaveChanges(), all of the commands are run at ONE time.

The only problem is that EF runs its commands separately behind the scenes, then I run the others right afterward.   It would be ideal to run everything as one single command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get it at design time with Sql Profiler, but I think you're meaning that you want it at run-time. Here's an example I found on how to do that:

```
public static void WriteGeneratedSql(EntityCommand cmd)
{
     cmd.Prepare();

     IServiceProvider isp = (IServiceProvider)EntityProviderFactory.Instance;

     DbProviderServices mps = (DbProviderServices)isp.GetService(typeof(DbProviderServices));

     EntityCommandDefinition definition = (EntityCommandDefinition)mps.CreateCommandDefinition(cmd);

     int commandId = 1;

     foreach (string commandText in definition.MappedCommands)
     {
          Console.WriteLine("Generated Command {0}:", commandId);
          commandId++;
          Console.WriteLine(commandText);
     }
}
```

Found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/6df9599f-c165-4a0e-9b92-ca58a8fc3816/).

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but its not quite what I need.  After inserting a new object or retrieving then updating an existing object,  I need to get the SQL that gets generated for these operations.   I can't get an EntityCommand object from the ObjectContext.

Comment: Just so we're clear, are you trying to get it at run-time, or design-time? That is, are you trying to get it just one time so that you can write a proc, or do you need to consume it somehow at runtime?

Comment: At Run-Time.  I want to basically get the generated INSERT/UPDATE SQL before it is executed, combine it with my own statements, then run all of the statements as one command.

Comment: Okay, I think I've got your answer here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jkowalski/archive/2009/06/11/tracing-and-caching-in-entity-framework-available-on-msdn-code-gallery.aspx. It's not perfect - you'll have to use their provider to get the tracing capabilities, but I think it's as close as we're going to get with this release. HTH.

Comment: This looks promising, but might be a bit of effort to get to work.  From the research we've done though, I think this is closest we're going to get.